# Find a formula for $F'$ and prove it.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f: \mathbb{R^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that $f,_2$ exists and is also continuous. 
Assume that $\phi :\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a differentiable function and let $a \in \mathbb{R}$.  Define $F:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $F(t) = \int_{a}^{\phi (t)} f(x,t)dx$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$. Find a formula for $F'$ and prove it.

Could someone give me a hint on where to start? I am completely stuck.

**EDIT: BELOW IS THE WORK I HAVE COME UP THUS FAR**

Recall that $F'(t) = \lim_{\gamma \rightarrow 0} \frac{F(t + \gamma) - F(t)}{\gamma}$

So, $\lim_{\gamma \rightarrow 0} [\frac{1}{\gamma}(\int_{a}^{\phi (t+ \gamma )} f(x,t + \gamma)dx  - \int_{a}^{\phi (t)}f(x,t)dx) ] = \lim_{\gamma \rightarrow 0} [\frac{1}{\gamma} (\int_{\phi (t)}^{\phi (t+ \gamma )} f(x,t + \gamma)dx + \int_{a}^{\phi (t)}(f(x,t+ \gamma) - f(x,t))dx)] = \lim_{\gamma \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{\gamma}[(\phi (t + \gamma)-\phi (t))f(c,t+\gamma )] + \lim_{\gamma \rightarrow 0} [\frac{1}{\gamma } \int_{a}^{\phi (t)}(f(x,t+ \gamma) - f(x,t))dx)]$

and this is where I get stuck..

Comment: This is Leibniz integral rule.

Comment: I have some work done, I will edit my original question with my work. Could you provide feedback on it? I got stuck and am unsure as to how to proceed. @HenryW.